# SQL count from the latest data and from two tables

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

I am a student currently trying out my mini project. My mini project is to check the status of the room. With this, I have created with tables.

The first table is Room Status. In the Room Status tables only got Id and Status.

**Data of Room Status**

[image: Room_Status]

The second table will be Room Current status. In it, it has Id, Site_Id, Room_Status_Id, Time.

**Data of Room current Status**

[image: Room Current Status]

I need an sql statement to count the latest status of the room base on the status I query, an example will be I want the status of "R'. Without having duplication of the site_id.

From the data the results I should have "4" when I query on "R".

I have tried a few sql statement, but could not get it to work.

The SQL Statement I tried and return what I wanted but I need a count of this:
"select Status, max_date = max(Time), Site_Id from Toilet_Status a inner join Toilet_Cur_Status b on a.Id=b.Toilet_Status_Id group by Site_Id, Status having a.Status = 'R'"

Comment: What SQL have you already tried and why didn't they work?

Comment: WHat do you mean the latest status of room??

Comment: @Tanjim Rahman the latest datetime in the table.

Comment: @RichBenner I got one statement working but this is to display out. Not to count.

"select Status, max_date = max(Time), Site_Id, COUNT(Site_Id) from Toilet_Cur_Status, Toilet_Status group by Site_Id, Status having Status = 'R'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully understanding your requirements but here's my attempt.

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #RoomStatus (Id int, Status varchar(1))
INSERT INTO #RoomStatus (Id, Status)
VALUES (900,'G'), (901, 'R')

CREATE TABLE #RoomCurrentStatus (Id int, Site_Id int, Room_Status_Id int, Time datetime)
INSERT INTO #RoomCurrentStatus (Id, Site_Id, Room_Status_Id, Time)
VALUES
 (1000,300,900,'2016-06-10 15:01:30.000')
,(1001,301,900,'2016-06-10 15:01:30.000')
,(1004,304,901,'2016-06-10 15:04:30.000')
,(1005,305,901,'2016-06-10 15:05:30.000')
,(1006,306,900,'2016-06-10 15:06:30.000')
,(1007,307,900,'2016-06-10 15:07:30.000')
,(1010,310,901,'2016-06-10 15:10:30.000')
,(1011,311,901,'2016-06-10 15:11:30.000')
,(1012,311,900,'2016-06-11 15:11:30.000')
,(1013,311,901,'2016-06-12 15:11:30.000')
```

This query will give you the number of unique values in Status based upon the Site_Id field.

```
SELECT
rcs.Site_Id 
,rs.[Status] StatusFlag
,MAX(rcs.[Time]) LatestTime
FROM #RoomCurrentStatus rcs
JOIN #RoomStatus rs
    ON rcs.Room_Status_Id = rs.Id
GROUP BY rcs.Site_Id, rs.[Status]
```

Results will be

```
Site_Id StatusFlag  LatestTime
300     G           2016-06-10 15:01:30.000
301     G           2016-06-10 15:01:30.000
306     G           2016-06-10 15:06:30.000
307     G           2016-06-10 15:07:30.000
311     G           2016-06-11 15:11:30.000
304     R           2016-06-10 15:04:30.000
305     R           2016-06-10 15:05:30.000
310     R           2016-06-10 15:10:30.000
311     R           2016-06-12 15:11:30.000
```

I know you've said that you should have 4 'G's and 4 'R's but I can't see how that can be with the data provided.

Edit, this might be what you're after

```
SELECT
a.Site_Id
,a.LatestTime
,c.[Status]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
        rcs.Site_Id 
        ,MAX(rcs.[Time]) LatestTime
        FROM #RoomCurrentStatus rcs
        GROUP BY rcs.Site_Id
    ) a
JOIN #RoomCurrentStatus b
    ON a.LatestTime = b.[Time]
    AND a.Site_Id = b.Site_Id
JOIN #RoomStatus c
    ON b.Room_Status_Id = c.Id
```

Results;

```
Site_Id LatestTime                  Status
311     2016-06-12 15:11:30.000     R
310     2016-06-10 15:10:30.000     R
307     2016-06-10 15:07:30.000     G
306     2016-06-10 15:06:30.000     G
305     2016-06-10 15:05:30.000     R
304     2016-06-10 15:04:30.000     R
301     2016-06-10 15:01:30.000     G
300     2016-06-10 15:01:30.000     G
```

And if you just want the result as a number, then use the following query;

```
DECLARE @SearchValue varchar(1); SET @SearchValue = 'R'

SELECT
COUNT(1) ResultCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
        rcs.Site_Id 
        ,MAX(rcs.[Time]) LatestTime
        FROM #RoomCurrentStatus rcs
        GROUP BY rcs.Site_Id
    ) a
JOIN #RoomCurrentStatus b
    ON a.LatestTime = b.[Time]
    AND a.Site_Id = b.Site_Id
JOIN #RoomStatus c
    ON b.Room_Status_Id = c.Id
WHERE c.[Status] = @SearchValue
```

You can change the parameter to R or G, it will give the result

```
ResultCount
4
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I been trying to solve thank you very much and may I know why you put a "#" in front of the table names ?

Comment: The # denotes a temporary (temp) table. I just used that for testing so that I didn't actually create any tables in my own test environment. You can replace those table names with your actual table names.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   select a.id,a.status,count(b.site_id) tot from 
    DataRoomStatus a join (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by site_id order by time desc) as rn 
    from DataofRoomCurrentStatus) b

     on a.id=b.room_status_id
where rn=1 group by a.id,a.status
```

Comment: I need to count the status "R", "G".

Comment: I need the latest datetime of the table. Example site_id of 311 at 31/06/2016 is "G" but at 01/07/2016 is "R". I need the latest one

Comment: So from the data, I have I will only have 4 of "R" and "G"

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    s.status, COUNT(r.site_id) count
FROM RoomCurrentStatus r
INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT site_id, MAX(time) maxTime FROM RoomCurrentStatus GROUP BY site_id ) latestRoomCurrentStatus
    ON r.site_id = latestRoomCurrentStatus.site_id
    AND r.time = latestRoomCurrentStatus.maxTime
INNER JOIN RoomStatus s ON r.room_status_id = s.id
```

The key part is the join to the Max query to filter the RoomCurrentStatus records to only include the latest records.  It's quite a common pattern, so a good one to understand!